# Hibernate :: unexpected token : FOR

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this query be used on hibernate with java:

```
String hql = "select part.ID,part.PartNumber,part.Name,parttype.Name,partkind.Name,
                      partdevice.Name,part.Count,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cabinet.Name FROM Cabinet as 
                      cabinet,Part_Cabinet as part_cabinet WHERE part.ID=part_cabinet.PaId and cabinet.ID =
                      part_cabinet.CabId FOR XML PATH('')),  1, 1, ''),part.Descript from Part as part,
                      PartDevice as partdevice,PartKind as partkind,PartType as parttype Where
                      part.Kind=partkind.ID and part.Type=parttype.ID and part.Device=partdevice.ID";
Query _q = session.createQuery(hql);
```

But I get an error:

```
unexpected token: FOR
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3473)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3168)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3040)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.additiveExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2750)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:568)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2518)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2474)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2343)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2269)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2224)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2010)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:1786)
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problematic part of the query is:

```
WHERE part.ID=part_cabinet.PaId
AND cabinet.ID = part_cabinet.CabId
FOR XML PATH('')
```

`FOR XML PATH` is a MSSQL 2005 [feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) absent in Hibernate. HQL is not a superset of SQL, and certainly it can't access database specific features.

You should probably use [native query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) for this use case as it allows you to query the database directly using SQL via Hibernate APIs.

<sup>And please link when [multiposting](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2449314) questions.</sup>